# Why does Joomla display this error?

Tags: php, syntax, joomla

I have made a website in Joomla and have i on my local machine. Everything works perfectly, but when i upload the site to my domain i get this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/www/fotohandleren.mathiasbak.dk/templates/fotohandleren_dk/index.php on line 1

I have edited the configuration file so it connects properly to the database (i am sure it does), but it seems to be a template problem. The template i use works perfectly on my local machine as i said.

I really dont understand it, i hope someone can help me :-)

Thanks

// Mathias Bak

Comment: you simply have syntax error. post first few lines from `index.php`. 
Also, make sure you are running your local site with latest source code. Disable php caching like eAccelerator, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not Joomla specific. As Alex pointed out you have a syntax error in your index.php file within your template. Possibly a missing $ or EOL ;

Comment: I know the errorcode is'nt Joomla-specific, but the error occured when i moved the files to the server. Just wanted to know if anyone has had this error. I think i need to update some parameter in the database... :( But thanks for your replys

Comment: Ok... VERY STRANGE !! I solved the problem by removing this line <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>... It must in some way conflict with PHP, but I dont understand how and why...?

Comment: perhaps this was sitting after the declaration of <?php

Comment: No, i did not have any php code in the beginning of my document. The xml decleration was the very first line.

Comment: As your template is called by the core Joomla files perhaps there is a missing php closing declaration - ?> in another file, e.g. index.php in your root. Your situation does sound odd though.